# Extracting array with a suffix

Tags: php, arrays

Generally, we can extract an array, and also add an prefix to it, like this

```
extract($array, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "myprefix");
// which will give me output like $myprefix_myarrayvar
```

But, instead, is there a way to set a suffix instead of prefix? Something like,

```
$myarrayvar_mypostfix;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no [`extract`](http://php.net/extract) option for that. So you need a workaround. You could either write a boring foreach or prepare the keys prior extraction:

```
extract( array_combine(preg_replace('/$/', "_suffix", array_keys($array)), $array) );
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should *never* use `extract` because it can make it very hard to tell where some variables are coming from, never mind possible collisions.  You don't save much with extract .. it's really just a tool of laziness.

Anyway, since you asked, no there does not seem to be a way to add a suffix with extract natively, so you would have to do it on your own:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
  ${"{$key}_suffix"} = $val;
}
```

Comment: I dont mind it that hard, to find where the variables are coming from, since I will be expecting them. So far as the matter about **collisions**, that's why we have prefix in extract.